# SVG image / shape scaled up is blurry on transition

Tags: html, css, svg

On Chrome, MacOs, I have this issue with SVG images and transition : **when the graphic is animating, it becomes blurry**.

On a project, it only happens on retina screens, but I did a jsfiddle that reproduce this issue : http://jsfiddle.net/0c2x7LaL/

```
<svg height="100" width="100" id="circle">
 <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>

#circle {
 transform: scale(1);
    transition: transform 2s ease;
}
#circle:hover {
    transform: scale(10);
}
```

It doesn't blur on Firefox, just on Chrome... Any idea ?

**Updated JSFiddle**

*(with translateZ(0) and backface-visibility, still the same)*

http://jsfiddle.net/0c2x7LaL/1/

Comment: I can't reproduce since I'm not on a high-res screen, but does adding `translateZ(0)` to your transforms make a difference?  This should force the element to be rendered on a new layer - might help with browsers trying to improve performance.

Comment: On the jsfiddle I provide, you can reproduce the blurry effect on non-retina screen (I can on Chrome/MacOs) if you hover the circle.

Comment: Well, actually, sometimes the circle gets blurry, sometimes not...

Comment: I just noticed that myself actually - if you let it grow to its full width and stay there for a couple seconds, it will be blurry on the next transformation until it fully shrinks...  My `translateZ` suggestion isn't working, unfortunately, but hopefully somebody can figure this out.

Comment: `backface-visibility: hidden;`? From my limited experience Chrome likes to use a raster of the svg instead of repainting the svg. It also depends on what type of element you apply the transitions to, i.e. `<div>` vs `<g>`.

Comment: backface-visibility: hidden; doesn't do the job this time...

Comment: In the fiddle, I use a svg element, on my project I use <img> with svg as src (I tried to put the svg code inside the html, it's the same).

Comment: Updated my question with translateZ(0) and backface-visibility in the fiddle.

Answer (score 4):

When doing CSS animations Chrome seems to use the original size raster during the transitions.

One solution is to use SVG animations instead.

```
<svg height="1000" width="1000" id="circle">
  <circle cx="500" cy="500" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red">
    <animate fill="freeze" dur="2s" to="400" from="40" 
                  attributeName="r" begin="mouseover"/>
    <animate fill="freeze" dur="2s" to="40" from="400"
                  attributeName="r" begin="mouseout"/>
  </circle>
</svg>
```

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0c2x7LaL/3/)

If you want to stick with CSS animations, another solution would be to make the large size the "original". Then reverse the scaling operations.

```
#circle {
    transform: scale(0.1);
    transition: transform 2s ease;
}
#circle:hover {
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0c2x7LaL/2/)

Whether this is workable for you depends on your circumstances.

Comment: That sounds clever ! I can't use SVG animation as I'm using a JS lib (which use CSS transition) to handle all animations, so I'll try the second option.

Comment: I think this answer is the most reliable in most cases, anyway, in my project, it couldn't fit.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using CSS `transform: scale();`, I just converted it to `width`.

In this case (img with SVG) :

```
img {
    width: 300px;
    transition: width 2s ease;
}
img:hover {
    width: 10000px;
}
```

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/0c2x7LaL/4/